# Validar campos vacíos en modal

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy intentando validar campos vacíos en mí formulario, se encuentra dentro de un `modal`, e buscado y no me resulta nada.

Esperando de su ayuda, este es mi código:

```
<!-- Modal para registros nuevos -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agrega nueva persona</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" size="10" id="nombre"  class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            <br>
            <label>Rut</label> <br>
            <input type="text" style="width:200px;height: 30px"  name="cliente" id="cliente" size="20" maxlength="8" required="">-
            <input type="text" style="width:35px;height: 30px"  size="4" maxlength="1" name="dv" id="dv" required=""> <br>
            <br>

            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" name="email" size="20" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            <br>
            <label>Sucursal</label>
            <input type="text" name="sucursal"  id="sucursal" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            <br>
            <label>Comuna</label>
            <SELECT name="comuna_id" id="comuna_id" class="form-control input-sm">
                <option>Seleccione una Opción...</option>
                <?php 
                $conexion=mysql_connect("192.168.36.4","crm","crmpass") or
                die("Problemas en la conexion");
                mysql_select_db("crm",$conexion) or
                die("Problemas en la selección de la base de datos");  
                mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                $clavebuscadah=mysql_query("select comuna_id,comuna_nombre from comunas order by comuna_nombre",$conexion) or
                die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clavebuscadah))
                {
                echo'<OPTION VALUE="'.$row['comuna_id'].'">'.$row['comuna_nombre'].'</OPTION>';
                }

                ?>
            </SELECT>

            <br>
            <label>Edad</label>
            <input type="number" name="edad" min="18" max="99" size="20" id="edad" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"  id="guardarnuevo" >
        Agregar
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Funcion JS :

```
function agregardatos(nombre,cliente,dv,email,sucursal,comuna_id,edad‌​) { 
    cadena = "nombre=" + nombre + "&cliente=" + cliente +   "&dv=" + dv + "&email=" + email + "&sucursal=" + sucursal+ "&comuna_id=" + comuna_id + "&edad=" + edad; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"POST", 
        url:"php/agregarDatos.php", 
        data:cadena, 
        success:function(r){ 
            if (r==1){ 
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php'); 
                $('#buscador').load('componentes/buscador.php'); 
                alertify.success("agregado con exito :)"); 
            } else { 
                alertify.error("Datos NO guardados" + cadena); 
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Estas usando JQuery?, lo mas conveniente es que las validaciones las hagas con js.

Comment: function agregardatos(nombre,cliente,dv,email,sucursal,comuna_id,edad){

 cadena = "nombre=" + nombre + 
 "&cliente=" + cliente +    
 "&dv=" + dv +
 "&email=" + email +
    "&sucursal=" + sucursal+
 "&comuna_id=" + comuna_id +
 "&edad=" + edad;
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"php/agregarDatos.php",
  data:cadena,
  success:function(r){
 
   if(r==1){
    $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
     $('#buscador').load('componentes/buscador.php');
    alertify.success("agregado con exito :)");
   }else{
    alertify.error("Datos NO guardados" + cadena);
   }
  }
 });

}

Comment: ese es mi funciones.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo quieres hacer con javascript lo puedes hacer con algo así...

```
function agregardatos() {
var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
var cliente = $('#rut').val();
var dv = $('#dv').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var sucursal = $('#sucursal').val();
var comuna = $('#comuna').val();
var edad = $('#edad').val();

if(nombre ==='' || cliente === '' || dv === '' ||email === '' ||sucursal === '' || comuna_id === '' || edad === '' )
{
    alert('Error debe completar todos los datos');
}
else
{
        var cadena = "nombre=" + nombre + "&cliente=" + cliente +   "&dv=" + dv + "&email=" + email + "&sucursal=" + sucursal+ "&comuna_id=" + comuna_id + "&edad=" + edad; 
$.ajax({ 
    type:"POST", 
    url:"php/agregarDatos.php", 
    data:cadena, 
    success:function(r){ 
        if (r==1){ 
            $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php'); 
            $('#buscador').load('componentes/buscador.php'); 
            alertify.success("agregado con exito :)"); 
        } else { 
            alertify.error("Datos NO guardados" + cadena); 
        } 
    }
});
}
```

}

Además debes veo que en el botón del modal no estas llamando a la función, por lo que deberías agregarle algo así:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"  id="guardarnuevo" onclick="agregardatos()">
    Agregar
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega esta función, la cual te ayuda a checar si el input esta vacío:

```
function campoVacio(obj){
    var correcto = true;
    if(obj.val()==''){
        obj.addClass("error-input");
        correcto = false;
    }else{
        obj.removeClass("error-input")
    }
    return correcto;
};
```

Agrega un pequeño css, para la clase del error en este caso. Mas o menos algo como lo siguiente:

```
.error-input{
    border: thin solid #d9534f;
}
```

Ahora para usarlo es de la siguiente manera, tomando en cuenta tu js:

```
function agregardatos(nombre,cliente,dv,email,sucursal,comuna_id,edad‌​) { 

  var correcto = true;
  if(!campoVacio($('#id_inputNombre')))
     correcto = false;
  if(!campoVacio($('#id_inputCliente')))
     correcto = false;
  if(!campoVacio($('#id_inputEmail')))
     correcto = false;
  etc...

  if(correcto){
    cadena = "nombre=" + nombre + "&cliente=" + cliente +   "&dv=" + dv + "&email=" + email + "&sucursal=" + sucursal+ "&comuna_id=" + comuna_id + "&edad=" + edad; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"POST", 
        url:"php/agregarDatos.php", 
        data:cadena, 
        success:function(r){ 
            if (r==1){ 
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php'); 
                $('#buscador').load('componentes/buscador.php'); 
                alertify.success("agregado con exito :)"); 
            } else { 
                alertify.error("Datos NO guardados" + cadena); 
            } 
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.